# How can I fix coroutine was never awaited?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a RESTFUL Flask API I am serving with gunicorn and I'm trying to continue running `parse_request()` after sending a response to whoever made a POST request so they're not left waiting for it to finish

I'm not too sure if this will even achieve what I want but this is the code I have so far.

```
from threading import Thread
import subprocess
from flask import Flask
import asyncio

application = Flask(__name__)

async def parse_request(data):
    try:
        command = './webscraper.py -us "{user}" -p "{password}" -url "{url}"'.format(**data)
        output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', command])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

@application.route('/scraper/run', methods=['POST'])
def init_scrape():
    try:
        thread = Thread(target=parse_request, kwargs={'data': request.json})
        thread.start()
        return jsonify({'Scraping this site: ': request.json["url"]}), 201
    except Exception as e:
                print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        application.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="8080")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I am sending a POST request similar to this.
`localhost:8080/scraper/run`

```
data = {
    "user": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "url": "www.mysite.com"
}
```

The error I get when sending a POST request is this.

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py:864: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'parse_request' was never awaited
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
```

Comment: This coroutin should be called by "await" keyword but instead you're just running that function in new thread. Also, you need a async loop to run coroutins.

Comment: AFAIK Flask/Werkzeug requests block I/O. Try [Sanic](https://sanicframework.org/) instead, the API is almost 1:1 to Flask and whatever you are trying to do should be easier there.

Comment: Awesome I'll check out sanic it looks great

Comment: Just a suggestion, try this - [Quart](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/quart) - its exactly the Flask API but fully async, and the code is excellent and works very well.

Answer (score 0):

So first things first, why are you calling webscraper.py with subprocess? This is completely pointless. Because webscraper.py is a python script you should be importing the needed functions/classes from webscraper.py and using them directly. Calling it this way is totally defeating what you are wanting to do.

Next, your actual question you have got mixed up between async and threading. I suggest you learn more about it but essentially you want something like the following using [Quart](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/quart) which is an async version of Flask, it would suit your situation well.

```
from quart import Quart, response, jsonify
import asyncio
from webscraper import <Class>, <webscraper_func> # Import what you need or
import webscraper # whatever suits your needs


app = Quart(__name__)

async def parse_request(user, password, url):
    webscraper_func(user, password, url)
    return 'Success'

@app.route('/scraper/run', methods=['POST'])
async def init_scrape():

    user = request.args.get('user')
    password = request.args.get('password')
    url = request.args.get('url')

    asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(
        None, 
        parse_request(user, password, url)
    )

    return 'Success'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8080')
```